# Checked="checked" not working in angularjs while checking a checkbox using conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I need to check a checkbox based on conditions. In my case, the function returns true for ng-checked.But after submit,the value shown as not checked. Any solutions for this?, greatly appreciated.
Here I have tried so far:

```
$scope.findViewTocheck = function (module) {
        if (module.x|| module.y|| module.z|| module.a) {
            return true; // module.x ,module.y ,module.z,module.a these are booleans
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="findViewTocheck(module)"> //Here I am checking the value to be checked or not.
```

UPDATE1:
I got like this after checking the checkbox based on conditions:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="findViewTocheck(module)" checked="checked">
```

But the value is 'false'returned.I need to check this as well. I only have checked="checked" attribute as extra after submit but I need ng-checked value as "true".Any other ideas to implements it?

Comment: In your browser, if you inspect the input line, do you have `ng-checked="true"` ?

Comment: So basically after you submit the checked status resets? Why don't you just set the check to checked after submitting, base this from before the submission

Comment: No.I have that same function call code in ng-checked attribute but extra one added as checked="checked" (Here I think so fault is)

Comment: can you please elaborate Mr.@Huangism can't understand clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by "_But after submit, the value is shown as not checked._"? Are you submitting using `ajax`? Or submitting a classic `form`?

Comment: The `ng-checked` directive overwrites the `checked` attribute. That is the way AngularJS works. What are you trying to accomplish here? Please review [AngularJS `input type=checkbox` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) and [AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

Comment: I'm just bind the value from model to checkboxes using ng-repeat while bind the boolean value to checkboxes I'm calling the 'findViewTocheck' method to check the checkbox but shows only checked="checked" not ng-checked="true"